# Getting average age of students and youngest student's name

Tags: c++, struct, file-io

I'm having some trouble with getting the average age of all students including getting the youngest student's name outputted. The output is supposed to come from a function call I wrote called ageCalc(...).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Student1.h"
#include "Student2.h"
#include "ageCalc.h"
using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("C:\\COMSC200\\a2data.input", ios::in|ios::binary);

    // Open the input file – if it fails to open, display an error message and terminate
    if(!inFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file!";
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File successfully open!\n\n";
    }

    // Use a pointer array to manage all the created student variables.
    Student1 **ptrArr = new Student1 *[SIZE];

    Student1 s;
    int total = 0;
    // read the first input record
    inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&s), sizeof(s));

    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        // dynamically allocate space for new student variable
        ptrArr[total] = new Student1;

        // populate the student variable from the input
        *ptrArr[total] = s;
        total++;

        // read the next input record
        inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&s), sizeof(s));
    }

    Student2 *st = new Student2[SIZE];
    for(int i = 0; ptrArr[i]; i++)
    {
        for(char fn: ptrArr[i]->first_name)
            st[i].fn += fn;

        st[i].mi = ptrArr[i]->middle_int[0];

        for(char ln: ptrArr[i]->last_name)
            st[i].ln += ln;

        st[i].cc = ptrArr[i]->campus_code;

        for(char sID: ptrArr[i]->student_ID)
            st[i].sID += sID;

        st[i].age = atoi(ptrArr[i]->age);
    }

    cout << "First Name" << setw(9)
         << "MI" << setw(15)
         << "Last Name" << setw(17)
         << "Campus Code" << setw(16)
         << "Student ID" << setw(15)
         << "Age" << endl;
    cout << "===================================================================================" << endl;


    for(int j = 0; st[j].age != 0; j++)
    {
        cout << st[j].fn << setw(8);
        cout << st[j].mi << "       ";
        cout << st[j].ln << setw(2);
        cout << st[j].cc << "          ";
        cout << st[j].sID << setw(16);
        cout << st[j].age << " " << endl;
    }


    Student2 *y;
    int avg = ageCalc(&st, y);

    cout << "Average student age is: " << avg << " years." << endl;
    cout << "Youngest student is: " << arr[i]->fn << " " << arr[i]->mi << " " << arr[i]->ln << endl;

    for(int x = 0; ptrArr[x]; x++)
    {
        delete ptrArr[x];
    }

    delete [] st;

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**ageCalc.cpp**

```
#include "Student2.h"
using namespace std;

int ageCalc(Student2 *arr[], Student2 *&y)
{
    int i = 0, sum = 0, index = 0, avg;

    while(arr[i] != nullptr)
    {
        sum = arr[i]->age + sum;
        i++;

        if(arr[i]->age < arr[index]->age)
        {
            index = i;
        }

    }

    y = arr[index];
    avg = sum / i;

    return avg;
}
```

**Student1.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT1_H_
#define STUDENT1_H_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Student1
{
    char first_name[10];
    char middle_int[10];
    char last_name[20];
    char campus_code;
    char student_ID[8];
    char age[3];
};

#endif
```

**Student2.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT2_H_
#define STUDENT2_H_
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Student2
{
    string fn;
    char mi;
    string ln;
    char cc;
    string sID;
    short int age;
};

#endif
```

**ageCalc.h**

```
#ifndef AGECALC_H_
#define AGECALC_H_
#include "Student2.h"

int ageCalc(Student2 *[], Student2 *&);

#endif
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Please, describe what you get and what you expected instead. Btw. all your average calculations is done on `int`. You know that the `int` stands for "integral"?

Comment: Concerning _I'm on a deadline by midnight._: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest) I'm sorry to say: "Sorry, that's your problem." (I repeated the word "sorry" to show you that I feel with you.)

Comment: That was a mistake, fixed it. The output for average age and youngest student is not showing up whatsoever. I'll post my expected output.

Comment: If the output for average age and youngest student is not showing, what do we see in the last picture? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: The picture is the expected output

Comment: Needless to say that pictures are not welcome for essentially textual output...

Comment: `ageCalc` seems to expect `arr` to contain a null pointer at the end of the student data but you haven't set any of the elements to null